# How to set --shm-size configuration for Puppeteer

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I have the same error as in [this](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1175) thread. The solution is to set `--shm-size=1gb`. 
From the Puppeteer docs, I found the following notes:

```
By default, Docker runs a container with a `/dev/shm` shared memory space 64MB.
This is [typically too small](https://github.com/c0b/chrome-in-docker/issues/1) for Chrome 
and will cause Chrome to crash when rendering large pages. To fix, run the container
with `docker run --shm-size=1gb` to increase the size of `/dev/shm`. Since Chrome 65, 
this is no longer necessary. Instead, launch the browser with the `--disable-dev-shm-usage` 
flag
```

I've tried the following code but with no success:

```
const args = [`--app=${url}`, `--window-size=${WIDTH},${HEIGHT}`, '--disable-dev-shm-usage'];
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless,
    args
});
```

How to propperly set --shm-size for the Puppeteer?

```
Node version: 8.9.3
Platform: Windows 10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Puppeteer function [`puppeteer.launch()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#puppeteerlaunchoptions) allows for an optional `options` [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object).

Objects have names (or *keys*) and associated values.

Therefore, in order to pass Chromium flags to [`puppeteer.launch()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#puppeteerlaunchoptions), you must use the `args` key with an array value that contains the relevant flags:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  args: [
    '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
  ],
});
```

In your example, you are passing the array without the `args` key.

Comment: adding arg, - --disable-dev-shm-usage, doesn't solve the issue - Error: Protocol error (Runtime.callFunctionOn): Target closed

Comment: what does `--dev-shm` do though?